# In the CHSH game, why do $a,b$ need to be the same unless $x=y=1$?

Tags: non-locality, nonlocal-games

In this [lecture](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/quantum15/lecture03.pdf), in the CHSH game section, it is claimed that a and b must be the same unless x and y are both 1. Can someone explain why? I see it the other way around.

Comment: It seems as if the reference you give uses a wrong definition. The players win if the XOR of their inputs (`a` and `b`) equals the product of their output (`x` and `y`).

Comment: @nippon The definition is not "wrong". It is equivalent to the standard definition up to relabelling of Alice's output. It's just non-standard.

Comment: thanks! i guess it was a notation misinterpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is that for $a,b,x,y\in\{0,1\}$, they require
$$
a\oplus b=xy.
$$
So, if $x$ and $y$ are both 1, it requires $a\oplus b=1$, i.e. $a$ and $b$ should be different.

If one of $x$ or $y$ is 0, then $a\oplus b=0$, meaning $a=b$. Therefore, $a$ and $b$ must be the same unless $x$ and $y$ are both 1.